# How do I batch-resize images in ImageMagick while maintaining aspect ratio and a max width and height?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I have a folder of hi-res images. It's a mix of JPG and 24-bit transparent PNG. I want to batch-generate thumbnails with the following rules:

- each image retains its format (.jpg in, .jpg out... .png in, .png out)
- each image retains its filename but gets moved to a /thumbnails subfolder
- each image retains its current aspect ratio
- the final dimensions of each processed image should be as large as possible with these constraints:
- max image width is 488px
- max image height is 220px
- aside from scaling, each image should retain all of its other properties

I am new to ImageMagick and have no idea what command(s) I would need to run in order to achieve this result. Ultimately, this is for a Jekyll project, but I would happily settle for being able to run this process manually via command line.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This Q is probably more appropriate on https:/superuser.com . StackOverflow is for programming Qs related to `if/then/else/endif` coding problems, and not how to use end-user tools. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: My apologies. I will make sure to take this into account before posting in the future. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ImageMagick command line mogrify is likely what you want and can do what you need. It processes a folder full of images. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify and https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize. The command would like be something like the following:

```
Create a new directory to hold your output, say, thumbnails.
Change directory to your folder with the images

mogrify -path path_to/thumbnails -resize 488x220 *
```

That command will process every file in your folder. If you have other formats, such as txt or other images that you do not want to process, then modify the command to restrict to just png and jpg as follows:

```
mogrify -path path_to/thumbnails -resize 488x220 *.png *.jpg
```

`add *.PNG *.JPG *.jpeg *.JPEG to the end of the line`, if you have different caps and spellings for suffixes in your directory.

There are different APIs for other programming languages. See https://imagemagick.org/script/sitemap.php#program-interfaces

Comment: Just a heads up, there was one issue with the command. `path_to` was causing this error:

`unable to open image 'path_to/thumbnails/image001.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2881`

But I was able to achieve the desired result by just removing `path_to` and running form the src images folder. Here's the command I used which worked like a charm:

`mogrify -path thumbnails -resize 488x220 *.png *.jpg`

I still marked your answer as correct answer becuase your command worked. I just needed to make that one tweak to get it to work locally.

Comment: FYI I'm on Mac OS 10.14.5. I installed IM via homebrew.
`Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-43 Q16 x86_64 2019-05-02 https://imagemagick.org`

Thank you again for your help @fmw42. I was completely lost and would have had no idea how to do this without your help!!! :)

Comment: As you found out, path_to/ was just a placeholder for your actual path.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry about that... ;)